# Strengthening the Cauchy condensation test

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the Cauchy condensation test:

> If $b_n \ge 0$ and $b_n \ge b_{n+1}$ then $\sum b_n$ converges if and
>   only if $\sum 2^n b_{2^n}$ converges.

It is possible to replace $2$ with any constant $C > 0$.

My understanding of this test is as follows : it says that $\sum b_n$ converges if and only if the $b_n $ tends to zero approximately with exponential speed. Approximately only because the terms in between $b_{2^n}$ and $b_{2^{n+1}}$ can be as large as equal to $b_{2^n}$ for the entire time before $b_{2^{n+1}}$.

Based on my understanding that I just described I would like to ask the following question:

Is it possible to replace the exponential function by something less fast. I had the idea of the following polynomial example:

> If $b_n \ge 0$ and $b_n \ge b_{n+1}$ then $\sum b_n$ converges if and
>   only if $\sum n^2 b_{n^2}$ converges.

But it is not true if $b_n = {1 \over n^{3\over 2}}$. Why is squaring not fast enough make the series  converge ?

Comment: Weakly duplicate to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695024/cauchy-condensation-test, see also [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) for the Schlömilch theorem.

Answer (score 2):

No, that does not work quite that way. If you have an index sequence $(n_k)$ of check points, then in the segment $n_{k-1}\le m< n_k$ one uses the estimate
$$
b_{n_{k-1}}\ge b_m\ge b_{n_k}
$$
and sums it up. The segment $k$ has repeating upper and lower boundaries for $n_k-n_{k-1}$ elements, thus
$$
\sum_k(n_{k+1}-n_{k})b_{n_{k}}\ge \sum_m b_m\ge \sum_k(n_k-n_{k-1})b_{n_k}
$$
This reduces to nice forms with similar upper and lower bounds if the index sequence is a geometric sequence, $n_k=a^k$, because then $(n_k-n_{k-1})=(1-1/a)a^k$ and $(n_{k+1}-n_k)=(a-1)a^k$.

If you use $n_k=k^2$, then $(n_k-n_{k-1})=2k-1\ge k$ and $(n_{k+1}-n_k)=2k+1\le 3k$. So the condensed series in this case is $\sum_k kb_{k^2}$, the factor is one degree lower than the index.

Similarly, $\sum_k k^2 b_{k^3}$ would be another condensed series for $n_k=k^3$.

---

So in the example of $b_n=n^{-3/2}$ one gets condensed convergent series
$$
\sum_k a^k\,(a^k)^{-3/2}=\sum_k \frac1{\sqrt{a}^k},\qquad
\sum_k k\,(k^2)^{-3/2}=\sum_k \frac1{k^2},\qquad
\sum_k k^2\,(k^3)^{-3/2}=\sum_k \frac1{k^{5/2}}
$$